# Combination of logic gates outputting single value (either 1 or 0)

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Here is my naive question, I would like to build s system of logic gates (not, &, or, nand, ...) where on input side I have all combination of {0,1} minimum input 4 values ($2^4$ combinations)

0000 -G-> 1

0001 -G-> 1

..

..

1111 -G-> 1

and on the output side I have just value 1 (or just value 0). I'm probably overlooking some simple solution. If it is possible, please write down the example if not, sketch of the proof would be great.
Thanks a lot

Comment: In practical electronics, you would just connect it to supply via a "pull up resistor" for a $1$ or to ground via a "pull down resistor" for a $0$. That would suffice to provide a voltage signal for most inputs to the pins of integrated circuits. However if you wanted a $1$ (high) or a $0$ (low) which can act as a current source or sink, respectively, you need to design something with a transistor or operational amplifier. Either way, it makes no sense to me to use complicated Boolean logic when your intended output is a fixed bit.

Comment: Yes, you are obviously right. It is not meant as an application of practical electronics but rather like a theoretical construct to achieve a specific class of mechanisms that doesn't have causal power upon it's inputs from informational standpoint...

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this for one bit.

A OR (NOT A)

This will always be true and will produce a 1 at the end.

A AND (NOT A)

will always be false, thus producing a 0.

Comment: I see your point and in theory it works, but for that purpose I would need the new gate that is not in "common logic gate set". The gate "splitter" that will duplicate the signal.

Comment: Each output can only be used on exactly one input?! What are you designing? I think I need way more context now. Splitting the signal like this is just a wire, not a gate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a set of gates to fulfill any combination of input/output combinations, you should use the [Disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form). There are some algorithms to give you the normal form from the original set of input/output combinations.